# map keyboard to layout / input method in uwp application

Tags: c#, keyboard, uwp, uwp-xaml

In Microsoft Windows you can change the input method to alternate keyboard layouts. For example you can change the input method to "United States-Dvorak" and when you type on your qwerty keyboard, the keys are mapped to the dvorak layout instead... ie pressing 'k' key on the keyboard triggers a 't' keycode.

I'd like to replicate this type of mapping within my UWP application without the user having to manually change the input method in windows settings. Is there a way to "bind" or "map" a key to a different key in a UWP app? How can I, for example, make it so that when a user types a 'k' into a TextBox control, have a 't' appear in the TextBox?

Comment: You are making this sound overly simplistic so that it's almost possible to solve. Still, reality is much, much more complex than you make it sound. Once you step outside the comfortable world of ASCII only,  there is no strict 1:1 mapping between pressing a key on the keyboard and a character being entered into a textbox (e.g. dead keys). Besides, this question sounds like you are really trying to solve something else, and you are mixing it up with what you think were a solution. What is the real issue?

Comment: @IInspectable If it was simple then I wouldn't be asking it here would I? :) I'm just trying to imitate having a different input method active for one textbox in my app. I'm working on a solution that uses a hidden textbox over top a visible one, but that's not a very pretty solution.

Comment: And... why don't you just attach the appropriate IME to the input widget, instead of faking it? Faking input will lead to so many issues further down, it won't be fun debugging (and you'll be doing lots of debugging). The effects are similar to what Raymond Chen has blogged about in [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).